# Linq Join() with composite key

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to make a request with two tables

Table Page :
Id, LangId (primary key)
PageTypeId, PageTypeLangId (foreign key)

Table PageType :
Id, LangId (primary key)

So How to do ? Here, i miss just do add PageTypeLangId

```
    return context.Pages
            .Join(context.PageTypes, p => p.PageTypeId, pT => pT.Id,(p, pT) => new { p, pT })
```

i would like :

```
 select * from Page inner join PageType on Page.PageTypeId=PageType.Id and     Page.PageTypeLangId=PageType.LangId
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Why aren't you joining on LangId (primary key)? It seems like that is part of what you need for the inner and outer selector described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx). What is your desired result?

Comment: i don't know how add an another field... i would like : `select * from Page inner join PageType on Page.PageTypeId=PageType.Id and Page.PageTypeLangId=PageType.LangId`...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following should work:

```
return context.Pages
              .Where(x => x.PageTypeLangId.HasValue)
              .Join(context.PageTypes,
                    p => new { Id = p.PageTypeId,
                               LangId = p.PageTypeLangId.Value },
                    pT => new { pT.Id, pT.LangId },
                    (p, pT) => new { p, pT });
```

Comment: i try this, but i have : `Error 16 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TOuter>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>, System.Func<TOuter,TKey>, System.Func<TInner,TKey>, System.Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. D:\website\Dev\Master\DAO\Repository\PageRepository.cs 95 17 DAO`

Comment: In that case your data types don't match. What's the type of `p.PageTypeLangId`? And of `pT.LangId`?

Comment: Nullable<int> for p.PageTypeLangId, p.PageTypeId and int for Id, LangId

Comment: @Olivier: I would use `HasValue` and `Value` instead. `HasValue` inside the `where` filters out all those pages without a page type language ID so that you can safely access the value in the join. Filtering them out doesn't reduce the result set, because they would be filtered out by the join anyway, because there will be no page type with a language ID of null.

Comment: If you are getting the "cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly" message, you may also need to name your keys the same for both anonymous objects.  They did this in the example, but it is easily overlooked.  .Join(context.PageTypes,
                    p => new { **Id** = p.PageTypeId,
                              **LangId** = p.PageTypeLangId.Value },
                    pT => new { pT.**Id**, pT.**LangId** },
                    (p, pT) => new { p, pT });

Comment: How to do similar thing, but I need LEFT JOIN instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63991230/how-to-make-linq-join-work-if-one-of-the-fields-in-composite-key-is-nullable